# How to disable Write access to a mysql table via sql command or phpMyAdmin for my xoops website issue

Tags: php, mysql, security

I have a website based on *php+xoops+mysql5.1*, I recently found my `xoops_users` table which stores members of the website is being attacked: there are new rows inserting into this table with random username/password/email from time to time, everyday I get around 20 dummy new members even though it's an inactive website with very rare page views.

I have done the following tasks, but it didn't solve the problem.

- Changed password for my DB
- Searched the whole domain, but didn't find any malicious scripts
  which would keep inserting rows into `xoops_users` table.
- Removed the member application form from website to ensure the attack is not through web GUI.

So my question would be:

**Is there any sql command I can apply to temporarily 'lock' my table to prevent it from being inserting new rows?** Such as only allow read access to the table. I'm also using phpMyAdmin to manage my database.

I know this would not fundamentally solve the problem, but I'm running out of ideas for handling the attack and I want to stop the table from increasing ASAP.

Other than that, if you happen to know something about the flaws in the member module of xoops, please kindly let me know. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you can achieve it through user permissions.

```
REVOKE ALL ON xoops_users FROM PUBLIC;
GRANT SELECT ON xoops_users TO PUBLIC;
REVOKE GRANT OPTION ON xoops_users FROM PUBLIC;
```

Something like this should help. You can also analyze which users you have and revoke rights individually.

Comment: Thanks for the info, let me try it :p